# Intuition for grad(F(x)) = F(x) grad(log(F(x))?

Tags: derivatives, intuition

It is straightforward to prove that $\triangledown f(x) = f(x)  \; \triangledown\log(f(x))$.

But is there some intuitive way to understand this identity?

Comment: $\log' x = {1 \over x}$ and apply the chain rule.

Comment: asking for an intuition, not a proof

Comment: Intuition for the chain rule?  If $f(x) = ax+b, g(x)=cx+d$, then $f\circ g (x) = ac x + ad +b$. Hence $(f \circ g)' (x) = ac = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$.

Comment: Divide across by $f(x)$ to see what I mean. The gradient of the composition $\log \circ f$ is $\log'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$.

Comment: yeah, I know how to prove it.  I'm looking for an intuitive way of understanding this fact.

Intuition.  Not proof.